# next-dev.js:89 TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am getting this error after building via `npm run build` and starting the it with `npm run start`

any idea why this error is showing ?

[image]

My whole layout is also wrong, I am guessing because of the tailwindcss error

this is my _app.tsx

```
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import "tailwindcss/tailwind.css"
import "../styles/styles.scss"
import { Provider, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { Application } from 'react-rainbow-components'
import { ThemeStore } from '../config/redux/ThemeStore'
import { theme } from '../config/react-rainbow/react-rainbow-config'
import { ThemeState } from '../config/redux/ThemeReducer'
import Navigation from '../components/navigation/Navigation'

const Child: React.FC = ({ children }) => {

  const isDark = useSelector<ThemeState, ThemeState["isDark"]>(state => state.isDark)

  return <div className={`${isDark ? "dark blackThemeColor test" : "white whiteThemeColor"}` + " min-h-screen font-body pr-0"} style={{ height: '150vh' }}>{children}</div>;
}
const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => {

  return (
    <Provider store={ThemeStore}>
      <Application theme={theme}>
        <Child>
         <Navigation />
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Child>
      </Application>
    </Provider>
  );
};
export default MyApp
```

All help is appreciated

Comment: Any reason why you're importing `"tailwindcss/tailwind.css"` directly in your `_app`? You shouldn't need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@juliomalves pointed out that I was importing tailwindcss/tailwind.css while it wasn't needed.

This was because when setting the project up I read this in the [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs)

> Import Tailwind directly in your JS If you aren't planning to write
> any custom CSS in your project, the fastest way to include Tailwind is
> to import it directly in pages/_app.js:

After relooking there was also this option

> Include Tailwind in your CSS Open the ./styles/globals.css file that
> Next.js generates for you by default and use the @tailwind directive
> to include Tailwind's base, components, and utilities styles,
> replacing the original file contents:

So I removed the tailwindcss import and imported in my scss file the tailwind like this:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Now when `npm run build` and `npm run start` the layout is correct and the error is gone